# Does the C standard specify behavior for reading input from stdout?

Tags: c

The following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[10] = "";
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", "hello");
    fscanf(stdout, "%6s", s);
    perror(NULL);
}
```

outputs `Bad file descriptor`. But section 7.21 of the [C11 draft standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21) doesn't seem to say anything about whether or not `stdout` is allowed to be passed to `fscanf`. Is this undefined behavior? Explicit (give standard quote) or implied (by omission)?

Comment: The code is C++, not C.

Comment: For the downvoters: feel free to rewrite the code to C. I don't care. It doesn't change the fact that the question concerns the *C standard* or that the C++ standard incorporates the C standard AND the C library.

Comment: Since **stdout** is an output stream, not an input stream, you cannot perform input on it. Is undefined behaviour. You should do that piping **stdout** to your application and read it from **stdin**.

Comment: "without modification" I guess no, they are "suitably adjusted to ensure static type safety", according to N3337 17.2

Comment: @LPs The C standard doesn't actually say that this is undefined. It's very vague about stdin, stdout and stderr.

Comment: Maybe could belongs to implementation defined? I mean that different systems can create a stream as write-only-stream or not?

Comment: The downvotes here are quite silly. This is actually a good question about a fairly badly defined part of the standard. It is obvious what the answer "should" be, but the standard isn't clear at all.

Comment: @user6269788 When c++ incorporates c libraries the handling follows the c++ standard, not a separate standalone c standard (like e.g. C11).

Answer (score 4):

The specification (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E), §7.21) doesn't actually mention any restrictions on input streams being passed to output functions, or output streams being passed to input functions. The only limitation in the specification is that the stream passed to `fflush` must be an output stream.

Comment: I'm glad that people are upvoting the correct answer, and not the answer that they want to see.

Comment: Not quite sure here. 7.21.3p11 says byte input functions reads characters as if by successive calls to `fgetc`, and `fgetc`'s specification in 7.21.7.1p2 says "for the input stream pointed to by `stream`", so this sounds like UB to me.

Comment: @T.C. To be honest I mostly looked for explicit mentions of output streams in regards to input functions, so missed that little bit. It is a bit vague, but I would rather say that using an output stream with `fgetc` is *unspecified* and not undefined. I checked `fread` and `fgets` closer as well, they don't say anything about "input" (or output) streams.

Comment: Hmm, my reading of `fgetc`'s specification is either there's an implicit requirement that the stream is input so it's UB because you broke the requirement, or it's UB by omission (4p2, "Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior."). And if that's UB, then so is reading an output stream using other byte input functions, since they read from the stream as if by `fgetc`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Unspecified behaviour occurs when there is a defined range of possible behaviours and the standard does not specify which one actually takes place.

Answer (score 2):

§4/2 (quoting WG14 N1570):

> Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International
>   Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the omission of any
>   explicit definition of behavior.

§7.21.3/11

> The byte input functions read characters from the stream as if by
>   successive calls to the `fgetc` function.

(and `fscanf` is a byte input function; §7.2.1/5).

§7.21.7.1:

> **The `fgetc` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int fgetc(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> <sup>2</sup> If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed
>   to by `stream` is not set and a next character is present, the `fgetc`
>   function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an
>   `int` and advances the associated file position indicator for the
>   stream (if defined).
>
> **Returns**
>
> <sup>3</sup> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if
>   the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream
>   is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. Otherwise, the `fgetc`
>   function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to
>   by `stream`. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the
>   stream is set and the fgetc function returns `EOF`. [footnote omitted]

The specification of `fgetc` repeatedly says "the input stream pointed to by `stream`"; it appears to me that this can be read in two ways: either there's an implicit requirement that `stream` points to an input stream, or the standard omits to specify any behavior when `stream` doesn't point to an input stream.

In the first case, passing a non-input stream to `fgetc` violates that requirement and is undefined behavior (see also §7.1.4/1; one might argue that this counts as "a value outside the domain of the function"); in the second case, passing a non-input stream to `fgetc` is undefined behavior by omission, because the standard says nothing about the behavior of `fgetc` in that case. So I would argue that `fgetc(not_an_input_stream)` causes undefined behavior.

If `fgetc(not_an_input_stream)` is undefined behavior, then so is `fscanf(not_an_input_stream, /*...*/)`, for the latter is specified to read characters as if by calling former.